# Setting a background image on a WPF image control?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, background, controls

I'm trying to have a background image on an image control in WPF, such as if I load a transparent PNG, I would still be able to see the background. Is it possible, or did Microsoft totally drop this feature with WPF and I have to rely on StackPanels/Grids/Whatever to achieve this ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Image` has no property to allow for that, just put the `Image` in a `Border` and set the [`Border.Background`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border.background.aspx) to an [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

No you need to images. Set the Window background to the image and set the root element background to an image

```
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="BackgroundImage.png"/>
</Window.Background>

<Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="ForegroundImage.png"/>    
</Grid.Background>
```

Answer (score 2):

As shown in tested code here set the Window background to an image brush. Notice **AllowsTransparency="True"** And **WindowStyle="None"** to drop the border.

```
<Window x:Class="khaosInstallerWPF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="616" Width="773" 
    ResizeMode="NoResize" Icon="images/khaos_Installer_UI.png" 
    AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="images\khaos_Installer_UI.png"/>
    </Window.Background>
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0"></Grid>
</Window>
```

Bonus: If you are using a shaped for be sure to make your form draggable

```
namespace khaosInstallerWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MouseDown += delegate { DragMove(); };
        }
    }
}
```